# Problem with document.forms[i][j].type, returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing a firefox addon. Here is a part of the quote

```
var cForm = ''; 
var doc = document;
for (i = 0; i < doc.forms.length; i++)
{
    var a = doc.forms[i].name + "";
    if ( a.search("itsMe") != -1)
    {
        cForm = i;
    }
}
```

//

```
if ( cForm != '' )
{
    for (i = 0; i < doc.forms[cForm].length; i++)
    {
        var sTotal = 'doc.forms[' + cForm + '][' + i +'].type';             
        if ( eval(sTotal) == "button")
        {
            return sTotal ;
        } 

    }
}
```

The first code works well. The 2nd code shows an error like: "doc.forms[0][0] is undefined"

whats wrong?? help...

Comment: Is the error really `doc.form[0][0] is undefined` or is it `doc.forms[0][0] is undefined`? Note the `s` in forms.

Comment: oops! u r right, its *doc.forms[0][0].type* gives undefined :(

Comment: @Michael, actually I'm making this addon for any type of webpages. So, there is no such HTML. I copied the above code & pasted on the navigation bar like *javascript:(the above code)*, it works! But when i put it in xpi (FF addon) then it don't work. It gives the above said error :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be in your use of `eval`; it might not know about `doc`, since it's not in scope. In general, you should try to avoid using `eval`. You really don't need it in this case, so try doing something like this:

```
if (i.length && typeof(cForm) != "undefined")
{
    cForm = parseInt(cForm);
    for (i = 0; i < document.forms[cForm].length; i++)
    {
        if (document.forms[cForm][i].type == "button")
        {
            return sTotal ;
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code gives this error *TypeError: doc.forms[cForm] is undefined*

Comment: I added some sanitization. Try it again, and make sure you set `cForm` before running my code.

Comment: i dont knw what happened.. but it dont work. So, i add *else { alert('not executed')}*. And i found out that the *alert* from the added *else* part is executing everytime. I'm now thinking that FF dont support document.form[i][j] in addons, though i'm using FF version 4.0.1 !! :(

Comment: finally i got it :) its *doc.forms[0].elements[0].type*

Answer (score 0):

`doc.forms[0][0]` could be a textarea, say, which would make it have no `.type`.

On a separate note, why are you using `eval`, exactly???